# How can I invert the output of wdiff?

Tags: unix, sed, diff, gnu

Given two files `old.txt` and `new.txt` generated e.g. via the command line with

```
echo "This is not what I want." > old.txt
echo "This is what I want!" > new.txt
```

I can run `wdiff` to generate a word-difference file:

```
wdiff old.txt new.txt > diff.txt
```

and reading with `cat diff.txt` will give me:

```
This is [-not-] what I [-want.-] {+want!+}
```

Starting only from `diff.txt` and parsing it, how can I recover the "original" `old.txt` and `new.txt` contents?

(this should be in principle *always* possible because `wdiff` seems to retain *all* the text information of the "old" and "edited" textfile, see e.g. [this gist](https://gist.github.com/davidefiocco/a97b1481a3ddb8c4dbbf0b2eae1def93) for another example)

One option is to build a simple (e.g. Python) parser using regex:

```
import re

def get_edited(diff):
  diff = re.sub('\[\-(.*?)\-\]', '', diff)
  edited = re.sub('\{\+(.*?)\+\}', '\\1', diff)
  return edited

def get_original(diff):
  diff = re.sub('\[\-(.*?)\-\]', '\\1', diff)
  original = re.sub('\{\+(.*?)\+\}', '', diff)
  return original
```

But it would be nice if there was a built-in way to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens with `wdiff` when files are mostly the same? I'm asking because `diff` won't display identical lines (except for diff context), so my gut says you'll run into issues if you're relying just on the `wdiff` output.

Comment: Let me clarify: I took one of my `README`s, deleted a single word on line 57 (about halfway through the file), and `git diff` contains 13 lines of output.  If `wdiff`'s output is similar in that it doesn't include everything before the context lines (in my test, context lines begin on line 52), you may not be able to do this.

Comment: @StephenNewell, yet wdiff instead seems to keep all the original+edited textfile information in its output. See https://gist.github.com/davidefiocco/a97b1481a3ddb8c4dbbf0b2eae1def93 for an example on a longer text. I have updated the question to reference this too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex seem to be the way to go.
See https://github.com/snukky/wikiedits/blob/master/bin/wdiff_to_parallel.py for an example on GitHub.